# Search in QComboBox

Tags: qt, search, combobox

Hi everyone I want to search a QString in QComboBox like this photo][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WOds.png)

Comment: You can look at "Completer Example" in Qt examples. MB it helps you.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/41123/solved-search-filter-inside-combobox-qcombobox/9

Comment: Actually that was not the solution for my problem